# ClaimsPrincipal in .Net API has a link istead of "sub" for user ID

Tags: .net, blazor, saml, claimsprincipal

I am developing an app using .Net mainly for educational reasons and I encountered an issue I can't find any clear solution for.
Just to clarify, I do not have any commercial experience in .Net, I'm just trying to gain some knowledge by myself.

I am using Blazor WASM as front-end, Auth0 as IDP with user storage and .Net web APIs to store some additional data.
I managed to obtain an access token for a logged user that carries a user ID in the "sub" claim.
This is a screenshot of access token taken from Blazor WASM app translated by jwt.io:
[Claims read from token taken from Blazor WASM app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uja0B.png)

This token is then passed with a GET request to the API that manages to read it. This is a screenshot from User.Claims property viewed in Visual Studio variable explorer with a breakpoint set in the API controller:
[Claims variable after passing token to API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK3Pk.png)

Now I do not know if this is a problem but as you can see every claim has a reasonable type like "iss", "aud", "exp" and so on.
The claim that stores the user ID however has this link as a type instead of "sub" though:
`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`

What I would expect is to obtain the value and assign it to a variable like this:

```
var subFromToken = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;
```

I can also do this and it works (the claim value is saved to subFromToken variable) :

```
            var subFromToken = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
```

Now that I'm not really familiar with the ways of identity in .NET my question is, is the latter a recommended and the best approach or should the first approach be somehow possible?
If so, what should I do so the ClaimsPrincipal does not overwrite "sub" with this link?

If more info about my configuration is needed I will post it, for now I'm not sure what might even be relevant to this.